# Strange URL generating from AB Pagination - /P8Mike/

Tags: pagination, ab-pagination

so, I've started noticing a couple 404 URLs coming up on Google Search Console with /P8Mike/ in the URL path (Example: /P8Mike/P40/).

These are originating from a paginated page on the website ending in /P8Mike/ which should not be a working page on our website, but for some reason, it is a working page on our website(s) and it's definitely not something that has been added on our end. It looks like it's somehow being generated by (we think) the AB Pagination plugin.

Has anyone else who uses AB Pagination noticed weird paginated pages like /P8Mike/ start cropping up?

I haven't personally created the templates, I've just come across the issue and am trying to see if anyone else has come across this issue as well...

At the top of the template, we have:

```
{exp:channel:entries disable="member_data|pagination|categories" channel="misc_list" limit="1"  refresh="1500"}
```

Inside a case:

```
<?php
    $segment3Pagination = (preg_match("/P[0-9]+/", "{referrer:segment_5}"));
    echo $segment3Pagination;
?>
```

Another example of usage:

```
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}
    {if "{freebie_4}" == "date" OR "{freebie_5}" == "date"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="person" dynamic="no" orderby="date" sort="desc" category="{exp:freebie:category_id segment='4'}" parse="inward" limit="8" paginate="bottom" disable="member_data"}        
    {if:else}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="person" dynamic="no" orderby="random" sort="desc" category="{exp:freebie:category_id segment='4'}" parse="inward" limit="8" paginate="bottom" disable="member_data"}      
    {/if}
{/exp:ifelse}
```

And then in the footer, we have:

```
{paginate}
    <div class="paginate-bottom">
        <p class="fright">Showing {abp_entry_from} - {abp_entry_to} of {abp_total_entries}</p>
        <nav class="pagination clearfix">
            <span>Page:</span>
            <ul>
                {if abp_has_previous}<li><a href="{abp_previous_link}/">«Previous</a></li>{/if}
                {abp_pages padding="no"}
                {if abp_is_current}
                <li>{abp_num}</li>
                {if:else}
                <li><a href="{abp_link}/">{abp_num}</a></li>
                {/if}
                {/abp_pages}
                {if abp_has_next}<li><a href="{abp_next_link}/">Next»</a></li>{/if}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
{/paginate}
```

I would like to pinpoint where this is originating from and fix it, so that we are having some random URLs crawled that don't/shouldn't exist. Thank you!